# Publish in Web Store

Tags: google-app-maker

From google drive, I would like users to be able to open files using my new app maker app. In app scripts, you can click register in the chrome web store. Is this possible with app maker? It would also be awesome for users to be able to simply click the icon from the apps section of their gmail, etc. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's ambiguous as to what you're looking to achieve from your question.

You might either be looking for how to use the [Drive Picker widget](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/widgets#drive_picker)

Or you might be looking to release an App Maker app in the Chrome Web Store, which is [not at all possible.](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment#application_access)

Comment: From the drive.google.com web page, users can right click on a document and choose "Open with". The "open with" menu links to 3rd apps and passes a doc id parameter for the selected document(s). I would like my app maker app to be one of the options available in the "Open with" menu. Does that clarify this issue?

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But App Maker is not going to handle the document like that.

If you need a document in your App Maker app, you can embed it within an iframe with the HTML widget. You can then pass the url of the document you want to load by a paramter in the url to a property on the page.

Comment: Many thanks for your responses. From the docs, it looks like you can snag the url parameters with something like 

function getParams(){
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
    console.log(location.parameters);    
  });  
}

That should allow me to get the doc id parameters. From there, I can embed the doc using the app maker widget, etc. I just can't figure out how to register the app maker app with google drive.